# Why can't we set null to an option of a select element of nullable type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Consider we have a model with a property `WillMarry` of `bool?` type. We can implicitly invoke all of the following without any problem.

- `obj.WillMarry=null;`
- `obj.WillMarry=false;`
- `obj.WillMarry=true;`

Now consider the following ASP.NET MVC view page.

```
<select asp-for="WillMarry">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="true">Yes, I will get married</option>
    <option value="false">No, I will not get married</option>
</select>
```

The model binding can populate both `value="true"` and `value="false"` to the `WillMarry` with `ModelState.IsValid` is set to `true`. However, it will set `ModelState.IsValid` to `false` if I use `value="null"`  instead of `value=""`.

## Question

If we can set `obj.WillMarry=null` implicitly, why can't the model binding set `WillMarry` to `null` via `value="null"` and without setting `ModelState.IsValid` to `false`?

## Edit

Probably I have to rephrase my question as follows.

- We can set `obj.WillMarry=false` implicitly and the model binder can also convert `value="false"` to `false`.
- We can set `obj.WillMarry=true` implicitly and the model binder can also convert `value="true"` to `true`.
- We can set `obj.WillMarry=null` implicitly HOWEVER the model binder can NOT convert `value="null"` (instead of `value=""`) to `null`.

Why is there such a weird behavior in the model binding just for `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form, your sending the name/value pairs of its successful controls in the request. If you select the first option with `value="null"` (rather that `value=""`) it would send `WillMarry: null`.

Everything that is sent in the request is just text (there is no concept of types) and its the responsibility of the `DefaultModelBinder` to convert the values to the property type. In your case, the `DefaultModelBinder` finds a matching property name in your model (a property that is `public bool? WillMarry { get; set; }`) and attempts to set it by converting the text `"null"` to a `boolean` which fails and `ModelState` becomes invalid.

In order to represent a `null`, the value sent must be an empty string.

Comment: Considering we can do `obj.WillMarry=null;` implicitly,  why can't `"null"` be converted to a nullable boolean by the model binder?

Comment: Because the text "null" is not the same as `null`. There is a difference between `bool?  WillMarry = null;` and `bool? WillMarry = "null";`. Image you have a property which is typeof string and you posted the value "null" - would you expect the `DefaultModelBinder` to set the property to `null` or to "null" :)

Comment: With the same way of thinking, `obj.WillMarry=false` is not the same as `WillMarry="false"` but the model binder can do it without any problem, right?

Comment: Because the `DefaultModelBinder` use value converters and "false" is converted to `false`. I cannot use a value converter to convert "null" to `null` because of the example I used above. If you want to study the source code you can find it [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs)

Comment: the model binder was build so it is able to convert "" to `null` for a nullable bool, which make sense. converting "null" to `null` would maybe make sense for c#, but consider, e.g, the same code written in VB.Net. Should the code convert "null", "Nothing" and everything is used as `null` in every NET language to `null`? I agree with the implementation they did for `DefaultModelBinder`

Comment: @SingleFighter, The source code is in c#. There is not a separate duplicate source code written in vb.net :)

Answer (score 1):

After your edit, I repost my comment as answer:

the model binder was build so it is able to convert "" to `null` for a nullable bool, which make sense.

Converting "null" to `null` would maybe make sense for c#, but consider, e.g, the same code written in VB.Net.

Should the code convert "null", "Nothing" and everything is used as `null` in every NET language to `null`?

I agree with the implementation they did for DefaultModelBinder

Comment: Is Razor a language-specific view engine? A single view page cannot adopt more than one language, can it? If yes, for c# programmer `value="null"` makes sense and for vb.net programmer `value="nothing"` makes sense.

Comment: @SingleFighter The DefaultModelBinder code is agnostic to the language is called from.  It behave the same way if it's called by a Razor parser, by c# code, vb code, and so on
,Net writers decided to allow conversion from "" to null, and not allow conversion from "null" "Nothing" or whatever else to null. This was the correct choice to me.